# Json String - How to add variables in the string

Tags: java, json, string, concatenation

I have a Json string like below

```
 String jsonRequestString = "{\"access_code\" : \"9bPbN3\" , "
                          + "\"merchant_reference\" : \"123\", \"language\" : \"en\",\"id\" : \"149018273\","
                          + "\"merchant_identifier\" : \"gKc\", \"signature\" : \"570fd712af47995468550bec2655d9e23cdb451d\", "
                          + "\"command\" : \"VOID\"}";
```

I have a String variable as

```
String code = "9bPbN3";
```

Question, how do I plugin the above string  instead of hardcoding it at the below place. i.e. instead of 9bPbN3, I want to use the variable code there.

```
   String jsonRequestString = "{\"access_code\" : \"9bPbN3\" , "
```

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is about (very basic) string concatenation operation. You can combine a string literal with a variable like `someString = "This is my value: " + variable`

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to consider the : and the \ as well or, just something like: "{\"access_code\" +code , "

Comment: You should wrap the variable in quotes if you'd like to pass it as a string: `"{\"access_code\": \"" +code + "\","`

Comment: I'd recommend using a JSON library to create and parse the JSON strings to reduce error-proneness especially if you're going to process critical production data.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. It works fine now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

If you are struggling to arrange the `"`'s the correct syntax would be

```
String jsonRequestString = "{\"access_code\" : \""+code+"\" , ";
```

Instead of formatting Json string manually, which takes alot of effort, consider using a library or util.

For ex (*going to use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library*) :

```
Request re = new Request();
re.setCode(code);
...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(re);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String yourVariable = "xyz";
String jsonRequestString = "{\"access_code\" : \"" + yourVariable + "\" , "
                      + "\"merchant_reference\" : \"123\", \"language\" : \"en\",\"id\" : \"149018273\","
                      + "\"merchant_identifier\" : \"gKc\", \"signature\" : \"570fd712af47995468550bec2655d9e23cdb451d\", "
                      + "\"command\" : \"VOID\"}";
```

Comment: you should use `"{\"access_code\" : \"" + yourVariable + "\"... ` =)

Comment: Erick, yeah, I just caught my mistaken quotation marks. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

General advice is to avoid crafting a json structure out of vanilla strings. Instead use a json parser/writer library for this operations.

Checkout http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html / http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html .

There a various other libraries and tutorials available.

If you don't want to go this direction, use a "known value" placeholder and substitute it. So the full json would contain  "access_code" : "@@ACCESS_CODE@@" and you would Substitute the placeholder with the real value. So your json string would be some kind of a string template.

Comment: IMO, this should be a comment, not an answer as this isn't really an answer to the question, just advice to not do what he's doing

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the `format` method like so:

```
 String jsonRequestString = "{\"access_code\" : \"%s\" , "
                          + "\"merchant_reference\" : \"123\", \"language\" : \"en\",\"id\" : \"149018273\","
                          + "\"merchant_identifier\" : \"gKc\", \"signature\" : \"570fd712af47995468550bec2655d9e23cdb451d\", "
                          + "\"command\" : \"VOID\"}";
String code = "9bPbN3";
String result = String.format(jsonRequestString, code);
```

Notice the "%s" I put in the place of where `code` would go. When you call the `format` method with `code` as a parameter, it puts it where the "%s" was.